For what $(a, b)$ does $(a + \sqrt{b})^{1000}$ come within $10^{-7}$ of an integer?
'For what $(a, b)$ does $(a + \sqrt{b})^{1000}$ come within $10^{-7}$ of a whole number?'. (a,b) are natural numbers. (may use calculator)
I came across the question 'Prove that $(1 + \sqrt{2})^{1000}$ is close to a whole number'. To prove this, you can consider $(1 - \sqrt{2})^{1000}$.
As $1 < \sqrt{2}$, $(1 - \sqrt{2})^{1000}$ must be very small. Expanding out the terms, you get: $1 - 1000\sqrt{2} + 999000 - ...$
Comparing this to the expansion of $(1 + \sqrt{2})^{1000}$, you get $1 + 1000\sqrt{2} + 999000 - ...$
$(1 + \sqrt{2})^{1000} + (1 - \sqrt{2})^{1000}$ will therefore produce an integer.
This expression will obviously come within $10^{-7}$ of a whole number. It also seems that it requires larger powers as $a$ and $b$ have larger values, but I'm having trouble for finding an inequality expression for when this will be within $10^{-7}$ of a whole number. Any help on this would be appreciated. Many thanks.

Hint: Note that $(1+\sqrt{2})^n+(1-\sqrt{2})^n$ is an integer. This only works, of course, because $|1-\sqrt{2}|<1$. For $a+\sqrt{b}$ with general $a$ and $b$, a different idea may be needed.

Oops yes I meant to write that second line from the bottom, I will edit it now. Thank you.

I'd guess you need numbers such that $b$ is close to $a^2$, e.g. $b=a^2\pm 1$.

Something I have realised, for $(a - \sqrt{b})^{1000}$ to be very small (the difference between $(a + \sqrt{b})^{1000}$ and an integer), $a - \sqrt{b} < 1$

Note that you do need $ | 1 - \sqrt{2} | < 1 $, instead of just $ 1 < \sqrt{2}$.  EG $1 < \sqrt{ 99}$, but $  ( 1 - \sqrt{ 99} )^{1000} $ is very large, because $ 1 - \sqrt{99} < -1$.

What lisyarus said. Solutions $(x,y)$ of $$x^2-ny^2=(x+\sqrt{n}y)(x-\sqrt{n}y)=\pm 1$$ are important & fascinating. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation

If $b$ is a square number then the exponent is obviously an integer.

for a "quadratic irrational" $x$ the condition called "reduced" is that  $x > 1$  and $-1 < x' < 0$ where $x,x'$  are the two roots   of some $a x^2 + bx +c $   where $a,b,c$ are integers, $a \neq 0,$   and the discriminant  $ d = b^2 - 4ac$   is positive but not a squares.

The numbers in question are quadratic irrationals which are Pisot numbers.
